# WPF Property return int null

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, null, int

I have an int property in my viewmodel that returns a custom class property. I check if the class reference is null, and in that case I want to return some empty value to the view in order to NOT show any value.

The code is like this:

```
public int percentage
{
get {
   if (customClass != null)
   {
      return customClass.getInt();
   }
   else
   {
      return 0;
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return a "no value" result, you should return `null`. Since that's not a valid value for an `int`, you have to change the type of the property to be `int?` instead:

```
public int? Percentage
{
    get { return customClass == null ? null : customClass.getInt(); }
}
```

If you have not seen the syntax before, `int?` is shorthand for [`System.Nullable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Don't forget that you can also transform the value of `Percentage` to anything you like really from inside the view by defining an appropriate [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) for the binding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have heard about nullable but never used it. Just one question, now in my setter how should I convert the int? to int? Just because I dont want to change my class type.

Comment: @Louro: That depends on what `null` means in this case, and even if it makes sense at all given your business logic. For example, what does `customClass` do? What is `getInt()` supposed to model? What does it mean that `customClass == null`?

Comment: My customClass is initialized with null and then assigned with the return of a service call. When the service call has some error, the customClass is null. In that case I want the View not to show any value.

Comment: @Louro: So it makes no sense to set the value to `null` from code. In that case, the setter can do `if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();`.

Comment: I already catch the service error Exception in the call itself. Now I just want to show a blank textBox to the user ...

Comment: @Louro: I 'm taking about the `Percentage` setter. Does it even make sense to have one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12856/discussion-between-louro-and-jon)

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a value type, so cannot be null. Instead, you could return `int?` (which is a shorthand for `Nullable<int>`) which can be null, or you could designate some specific `int` value such as `0` as appropriate for when `customClass == null`. That of course depends on your requirements.

```
public int? Percentage {
    get {
       if (customClass != null)
          return customClass.getInt();
       else
          return null;
    }
}
```

Anything which calls `Percentage` will need to check `Percentage.HasValue` to see if it's null or not, and use `Percentage.Value` to extract the actual integer, which will work if `Percentage.HasValue` is `true`.